# Does this operator have a dense range?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $U:L^2(\mathbb R_+,\frac{\mathrm d x}{x})\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb R_+,\frac{\mathrm d x}{x})$ be given by:
$$(Uf)(x)=\frac {xf(\sqrt{x^2+1})}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
I want to show that this operator has dense range as a first step to show that it is unitary. However, I'm not even sure whether it is true to begin with. So my question is: Does the operator have dense range and if so, how can it be proved?

Comment: It might be a good idea to tell us where you found this problem, or why this problem is relevant to you.

Comment: If $f(x)=0$ for $x\ge 1$ then $Uf=0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks! Unfortunately, I don't have enough privileges to upvote comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for a given $g\in L^2(\mathbb{R}_+,dx/x)$  the equality $${x\over \sqrt{x^2+1}}f(\sqrt{x^2+1})=g(x)$$ has a solution
$$f(y)=\begin{cases} 0, & 0<y\le 1 \\ 
 {y\over \sqrt{y^2-1}}g(\sqrt{y^2-1}),& y>1\end{cases}$$ The function $f$ belongs to     $L^2((1,\infty),dy/y)\subset L^2( \mathbb{R}_+,dy/y)$ and $Uf=g.$ Thus $U$ is surjective. Moreover $$\|f\|^2=\int\limits_1^\infty {y^2\over y^2-1}|g(\sqrt{y^2-1})|^2{dy\over y} \\ =\int\limits_0^\infty |g(x)|^2\,{dx\over x}=\|Uf\|^2$$
In order to make $U$ a unitary operator the domain should be replaced by $L^2((1,\infty),dx/x).$